# Solve: Consider $f (x) = 90x^2 + 20x + 1$ then sum of digits of $f (111111)$ is...?

Tags: quadratics

This is the question asked in my maths paper of quadratic equations but I am unable to understand which concept will be used here . Please help me in this.

Comment: Just to note: $111111^2 =12345654321$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have calculated the answer. It is 13.
$f(1)=111$, sum of digits$=3$.

$f(11)=121*90+20*11+1=11111$, sum of digits$=5$.

In same way when you calculate this sum of digits of

$f(111)=7$

$f(1111)=9$

$f(11111)=11$

$f(111111)=13$

Your answer. The form written is the trick. ($90x^2+20x+1$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Complete the square:
$$90x^2+20x+1=90(x+\frac19)^2-\frac19=\\
=\frac{10}{9}(9x+1)^2-\frac19=\frac{10(9x+1)^2-1}{9}.$$
Answer: $13$.

Comment: right, $(10^{13}-1)/9$ gives the result.